# expected package.json (path)\package.json does not exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, build

When i use  commond

> expo build:android Apk

I came the error massage

he expected package.json (path)\package.json does not exist.

please solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error came becuase commond is wrong. Then i use

> expo build:android

now works